# Run two completely different sqli queries inside one script

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm new to `php`.

I have this page:

```
<?php
function renderForm($id, $StaffFullName, $StaffJobPosition, $error)
{
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
<?php
// if there are any errors, display them
if ($error != '')
{
echo '<div>'.$error.'</div>';
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
<div>
<p>ID: <?php echo $id; ?></p>
Name: * <input type="text" name="StaffFullName" value="<?php echo $StaffFullName; ?>"/><br/>
Job Position: * <select name="JobPosition">
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM LUT_JOBPOS";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
if ($StaffJobPosition == $row['JobposID'])
{
echo "<option value='{$row['JobposID']}' selected='selected'>{$row['JobposTitle']}</option>";
}
else {
echo "<option value='{$row['JobposID']}'>{$row['JobposTitle']}</option>";
}
} 
$result->close();
?>
</select><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update">
<input type="button" onClick="parent.location='view.php'" value="Back">
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
}
// connect to the database
require_once('../../authenticate.php');

// check if the form has been submitted. If it has, process the form and save it to the database
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
// do some funky stuff
}
else
// if the form hasn't been submitted, get the data from the db and display the form
{
// get the 'id' value from the URL (if it exists), making sure that it is valid (checking that it is numeric/larger than 0)

if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] > 0)
{

// query db
$id = $_GET['id'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM STAFF WHERE StaffID=$id";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$result->close();

// check that the 'id' matches up with a row in the database
if($row)
{
// get data
$StaffFullName = $row['StaffFullName'];
$StaffJobPosition = $row['StaffJobPosition'];

// show form
renderForm($id, $StaffFullName, $StaffJobPosition, '');
}
else
// if no match, display result
{
echo "No results!";
}
}
else
// if the 'id' in the URL isn't valid, or if there is no 'id' value, display an error
{
echo 'Error!';
}
}
?>
```

So, what happens here is this:

When you open the page like `edit.php?id=1`, it fetches the data of the associated record from `STAFF` table and shows them on page for the user to edit them.
This part of the code works fine. 
I also want the user to be able to select "Job Position" possible values from a drop down box. The drop down box should get its data from another table in database, `LUT_JOBPOS`.
This is the part of the code that doesn't work.

I was using `mysql_query` commands before on this page and it worked perfectly. However I was told to switch on `mysqli_query` instead.
Since I did the conversion I can't find how to run these two queries on the same script.
I messed a little bit with the `require_once` command and depending on where I call it I can run one query or another, but never both of them.

Looking at the logs of my web host the only thing I can see that may be relevant to my issue is:

> "mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Notice: Undefined variable: connection in /var/www/vhosts/myhostdomain.com/httpdocs/prod15/admin/staff/edit.php on line 24"

The connection variable comes from `authenticate.php` and it holds the connection parameters to the database. I'm sure it's set otherwise the first query (that gets the user data) wouldn't work.

I read somewhere that you can't run two `sqli` queries on the same script.
Then how I'm supposed to use a `LUT` table (lookup table)?

PS: I know that for showing the data I can use a `UNION` and that's what I do.
But when I edit the data I want the user to be able to select only from the possible values that exist on the `LUT` table (drop down select box)

Any help?

Comment: You want to solve several issues, can you break them in parts so that we can better understand.

Comment: It's only one issue: Second `sqli_query` (the one that reads data from `LUT_JOBPOS` table in order to add them on a select box) does not execute. I'm just giving out as much info as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of issues in your code. You really need to review it before use it in some real application, but for your specific problem, here is my guess.

You are calling the line `$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);` in the line 24 and only after taht you call `require_once('../../authenticate.php');`.

As you said, the `$connection` var is defined in the authenticate.php, so in the line 24 is undefined.

Try to use `require` in the first line of your php script.

Comment: Line 24 belongs to the function that prints the page. The function gets called only after I have fetched the data from `STAFF` table. Therefore the `require_once` has been called allready.

Comment: Now I have seen that it has a function in your code. However, I keep my answer. As i said, your code have some issues and maybe it is a [scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) problem. See the PHP manual page , specially this [comment](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#55595). maybe it helps you to undestand the possible problem.